# Why can't I detect the button element using enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, debugging, enzyme

I used `npm install --save enzyme react-test-renderer enzyme-adapter-react-16` to start things off.  I wrote the code below then ran `npm test` to get the output I got in `Terminal`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here's `CheckoutButton.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './CheckoutButton.css';

const button = (props) => (
    <button className={classes.Button} id="test" onClick={props.clicked}>Checkout</button>
);

export default button;
```

Here's `CheckoutButton.test.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import CheckoutButton from './CheckoutButton';

configure({
    adapter: ({adapter: new Adapter()})
});

describe('<CheckoutButton />', () => {
    it('should logout upon clicking the button', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<CheckoutButton/>);
        expect(wrapper.find("button")).toHaveLength(1);
    });
});
```

Here's what I get in the Terminal:

```
Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.572s, estimated 3s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

Comment: try ```wrapper.find('#test')```?

Comment: @LukeHutton I tried that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [adapter config](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/index.html) doesn't seem to be correct.

Try:

```
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

instead of:

```
configure({
   adapter: ({adapter: new Adapter()})
});
```

Comment: omg, I'm so clumsy, thank you!... now It says `Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total`.  I want it all to pass

Comment: I don't get how I failed one of the tests.

Comment: @sp92 I see only one test in question... however, try play with `console.log(wrapper.debug())` it's really helpful to catch issues

Answer (score 0):

Because it's in your root while you are trying to find it in children. Your expect should be `expect(wrapper.type()).toEqual('button');`

Comment: That's strange because it should work. https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/type.html

Comment: @sp92 As far as I know `expect(wrapper.contains('button')).toBeTruthy()` should work as well

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, it still doesn't work.  This is so weird.

Comment: @sp92 that's really weird. I'd suggest to try also making your Button component a named function and use capitalized name (`export default function Button() { ... }`). Maybe it will help...

Answer (score 0):

In `CheckoutButton.js` update your code to:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './CheckoutButton.css';

const CheckoutButton = (props) => (
    <button className={classes.Button} id="test" onClick={props.clicked}>Checkout</button>
);

export default CheckoutButton;
```

As per React component naming convention, you should always name your component in PascalCase.

Component name should always start from Capital letter. Making this change will pass the test case.

More detail cann be find here: [Component Naming Convention](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

Comment: Can you share test case fail logs to get more details?